# Word for students who follow a brighter student

Tags: word-request, nouns

There are three students - **A** , **B** and **C**.

**A** is very bright in the class.
Whatever **A** says, **B** and **C** just follow **A**, even they are not agreed with A.
Because, **B** and **C** are afraid to be beaten by **A** in front of the class.

Is there a word to describe a person like **B** and **C**?

Comment: This is unclear to me: "Whatever A says, B and C **dare to against**."

Comment: It's a kind of B and C are always follow what A says, even they are not agreed. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Perhaps the word you're looking for is **submissive.**

Comment: I guess @Ronald really did mean **beaten**: **beaten into submission**

Comment: Here, I don't mean **beaten** as **hit or punch someone to submit**. 
As I say, **A** is brighter than **B** and **C**.. so, **A** can make them to  get embarrassed in front of the class. In my opinion, the word **Submissive** is pretty closed with what I want to say. Thanks Peter.

Comment: @Ronald Maybe **timid**, **docile**, **kow-tow**, **passive** these all mean will not put up a fight, but is reflective of the individual being **submissive** without the **domination** connotation of **submission**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Lackey (noun)
>
> derogatory - a person who is obsequiously willing to obey or serve
>   another person or group of people.
>
> synonyms: toady · flunky · sycophant · flatterer · minion

This is a pejorative, so how you *say* the word *means more* than the word itself. However, even if you do *say it with a smile* you are still *calling two people* spineless, so be careful.

Your next option is *ironic*. The word will be intentionally used out of context to highlight how silly the whole situation has become:

> Retinue (noun)
>
> 1.a group of advisers, assistants, or others accompanying an important person.
>
> synonyms: entourage · escort · company · court

"Here's comes Person A and *his retinue* to save the day."

Answer (score 0):

1. B and C are "followers" if you refer to them together.
   Or - B is a follower and so is C.
2. B and C are 'overawed' by A.
3. B and C are 'sheep'.
4. B and C are 'toadies'
5. B and C are 'brownnosers'
6. B and C are 'sycophants'

The first option is a noun for B and C.
The second option is verb describing what A does to B and C.

Comment: Not sure whether "a word" you are looking for is a noun, verb, or adjective.

Comment: I would prefer Noun form.